# RecyclerView last row cut off on the bottom

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

For some reason the last row of my recycler view is cut off like this and I can't scroll down further.

[RecyclerView picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2cPd.png)

I have a custom adapter for it. If I make the row height more smaller I can make the bottom appear but I want the row to be that height. Is there a way to make the recycler view scroll further down so the last row appears?

layout xml for my custom adapter:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding = "12dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewID"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="1"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewSubject"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textViewID"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textViewID" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewLastmodified"
                android:layout_width="182dp"
                android:layout_height="23dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="Last Modified: "
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textViewSubject"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewSubject" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewDate"
                android:layout_width="81dp"
                android:layout_height="68dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:text="Created on: "
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

XML layout of the activity with my recyclerview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".ShowActivity">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView2"
        android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_width="409dp"
        android:layout_height="729dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Please post your xml layout with RecyclerView

Comment: @VasilyKabunov Edited to include recyclerView

Comment: in your main xml set constraintlayout height `match_parent` instead of `wrap_content` and also set recycler view's height `729dp` to `0dp`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the issue you can 1) set root view height to `match_parent` and 2) replace fixed size of recyclerview to `0dp` to fit the screen.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" <!-- 1 -->
    tools:context=".ShowActivity">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView2"
        android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_width="409dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp" <!-- 2 -->
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```